# Cross validation method with multiple folds, train/test ratio and even class in folds

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to do a cross validation with multiple fold with a 70%/30% train/test set split in folds and  even class in my folds:

For example, I have:
1000 observations with about 800 class "0" and 200 class "1",
I would like to do 10 folds <s>with each fold having around 70 observations in train set and 30 observations in test set</s>,
and inside each fold, the train set and test set  should have 50% class "0" and 50% of class "1", <s>so around 35 class "0" and 35 class "1" in train test and 15 class "0" and 15 class "1" in test test</s>

First is it a valid approch and is there any method to do it in Python ?

Edit: apparently, if I choose 10 fold, it will be a 90%/10% ratio for my train/test set ?

Comment: Why do you want to alter the class balance from 80/20 to 50/50 for your cross-validation? Do you expect a 50/50 balance in your production data?

Answer (score -1):

There is clear class imbalance in the data so first apply class balancing techniques like SMOTE on train data after train-test-split. Don't attempt to make any changes in test to balance the classes. Now that your train data has 50-50 classes, you can apply cross-validation if you wish.